# How to persist dark mode in Redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I wrote a theme changer using Redux-Toolkit (RTK) Query, but I can't manage to find a way to make the page persist in the same theme it was before refreshing it.

Here's the code:

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const themeSlice = createSlice({
  name: "themeSlice",
  initialState: true, // Initial value is light theme
  reducers: {
    toggleTheme: (state) =>{
      return state = !state; // Changes the theme to dark
    }
  }
});

export const { toggleTheme } = themeSlice.actions
export default themeSlice.reducer;
```

Redux Store:

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    theme: themeReducer,
  },
})
```

I personally want to save the theme name in the localStorage. I tried several tutorials, but none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trivial solution would be to locally set the initial state value from localStorage and persist the state changes to localStorage.

Example:

```js
// Read initial state value from localStorage or provide 
// default fallback value
const initialState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("theme")) ?? true;

export const themeSlice = createSlice({
  name: "themeSlice",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    toggleTheme: (state) => {
      // Compute the next state
      const nextState = !state;

      // Persist the next state value
      localStorage.setItem("theme", JSON.stringify(nextState));

      // Return the next state value
      return nextState;
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit how-to-persist-dark-mode-in-redux-state]

Reducer functions are supposed to be pure functions, e.g. free of side-effects, so the above solution may be frowned-upon. [Redux-Persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) is a common and popular library solution for persisting and hydrating a Redux store. If you are fairly familiar with Redux already then it is about a 5-15 minute integration.

Basic example:

```js
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  theme: themeReducer,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { store, persistor } from "../path/to/store";

...

<Provider store={store}>
  <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
    <App />
  </PersistGate>
</Provider>
```

[image: Edit how-to-persist-dark-mode-in-redux-state (redux-persist)]

Comment: Your localStorage method didn't work for me. I saw the output in my broswer, but after refreshing the page, it went back to light mode even though its value was stored.

The redux-persist kept the page dark and I couldn't revert back to light mode because of it

Comment: @YairYakobson Oh sorry, failure on my part with the value being stored being a boolean. Only need to provide fallback value for returned null values from localStorage. I've added a running codesandbox demo. I'll work on providing one also for using Redux-Persist.

Comment: Thank you for that. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @YairYakobson Redux-Persist codesandbox demo up as well. Please do check them both out.

Comment: Yes I did and I already implemented it.